# cornerWidget disappears when there isn't any tab

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm working on a window which has an empty QTabWidget when created. The user can add some tabs with a `QPushButton` set as `cornerWidget`.

My problem is that the `cornerWidget` works fine when there are tabs, but disappears when there isn't any tab. See code below:

```
class myWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        tabW = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        self.layout().addWidget(tabW)

        #tabW.addTab(QtGui.QWidget(), 'tab1')

        tabW.setCornerWidget(QtGui.QPushButton())

        self.show()

myWIndow01 = myWindow()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the correct behaviour of `QTabWidget`: when it's empty, it displays nothing.

A workaround is to set the minimum size of the button, like this:

```
self.button=QtGui.QPushButton("my button")
tabWidget.setCornerWidget(self.button)
tabWidget.cornerWidget().setMinimumSize(self.button.sizeHint())
```

Comment: Great workaround! I assume for better style one would need to use QTabBar and QStackedWidget.